# Updating ngModel of custom element from inside angular controller instead of Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, custom-controls

I have a directive something like the following for a custom control

```
myApp.directive('myControl', function ($filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { ngModel: "=" },
        templateUrl: 'some template path',
        controller: 'myControlController'
    }
});
```

I define the all the functionality of this control in a separate controller block:

```
myApp.controller('myControlController',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.value=$scope.ngModel;
    //$scope.ngModel='newValue';
}]);
```

I have a parent controller within which I create a myControl as follows:

```
myApp.controller('componentController',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.myModelValue='OriginalValue';
}]);
```

The following is the html content of the parent page:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="componentController">
            <my-control ng-model="myModelValue"></my-control>
            {{myModelValue}}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, I wish to update the value of the ngModel to 'newValue' from the original value of 'OriginalValue' using something like

//$scope.ngModel='newValue';

Is there any way to achieve this other than doing it from a directive or using a $parent operation.

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you should always be using `$scope.myModelValue`, _not_ `$scope.ngModel`.

Comment: myModelValue is the model of the componentController which I'm assigning as an ng-model. If we resort to naming the model rigidly, the utility of an ng-model in a reusable control would diminish.

Comment: It turns out that I had a ng-controller tag inside the html template of my custom control. Removing that did the trick.